# LINQ Expression for IN clause with Largest Date

Tags: mysql, sql, linq

I have the following query which needs to be write as LINQ

```
select * from sales s 
where area in ('f1','f2','f3') and sdate =(select max(sdate) from sales ss where ss.area= s.area)
```

I am confused about max date.

**My current Code:**

```
        var maxDate = (from A in _context.sales
                       where inputArray.Contains(A.area)
                       select A.sdate)
                       .Max();
        var Model =
        (from A in _context.sales
         where inputArray.Contains(A.area) && A.sdate== maxDate  
         select ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Speaking about

```sql
sdate =(select max(sdate) from sales ss where ss.area= s.area)
```

condition, or more precisely

```sql
s.sdate = (select max(ss.sdate) from sales ss where ss.area = s.area)
```

you could use nearly the same subquery syntax - just the `Max` should be outside the LINQ *query syntax*, or just use LINQ *method syntax* for that part, e.g. either

```c#
from s in _context.sales
where inputArray.Contains(s.area)
    && s.sdate == (from ss in _context.sales where ss.area == s.area select  ss.sdate).Max()
```

or

```c#
where inputArray.Contains(s.area)
    && s.sdate == _context.sales.Where(ss => ss.area == s.area).Max(ss => ss.sdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Expression x => list.Contains(x) will be converted to IN sql query

```
var list = new List<string>{"f1","f2","f3"};
var query = context.Sales
            .Where(x => list.Contains(x.Area))
            .GroupBy(x => x.Area)
            .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y=>y.sDate).First());
```

Comment: i got about IN. I confused with max date. Currently i took max date in a variable and added to the and condition in the where clause. Can i have any direct option? I updated my current code

Comment: try using the groupBy function with OrderByDescending by date, then select the first one from each group